# android sqlite exception no column name found

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying insert values into sqlite database android, The following is ma code

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
  public static final String COL_DATETIME = "date_time";    
  public static final String COL_IMEI = "imei";
  public static final String COL_CATEGORY = "category";
  public static final String COL_DESCRIPTION= "desc";
  public static final String COL_LAT = "locationx";
  public static final String COL_LONG = "locationy";

  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cmas";
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "survey_details";

  public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context paramContext, String paramString, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory paramCursorFactory, int paramInt)
  {
    super(paramContext, paramString, paramCursorFactory, paramInt);
  }

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase)
  {
    paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE survey_details(date_time TEXT,imei TEXT,category TEXT,locationx REAL,locationy REAL,desc TEXT);");
  }

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
  }
}
```

In button listener i am doing like this:

```
ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
                  localContentValues.put("date_time","zzz");
                  localContentValues.put("imei","a");
                  localContentValues.put("category","b");
                  localContentValues.put("locationx",99.999);
                  localContentValues.put("locationy", 11.77);
                  localContentValues.put("desc", "c");
                  MainActivity.this.profile.insert("survey_details", "date_time", localContentValues);
```

But i am getting an exception like the following:

```
04-21 16:54:51.036: E/SQLiteLog(953): (1) table survey_details has no column named description
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953): Error inserting category=b locationx=99.999 locationy=11.77 date_time=zzz description=c imei=a
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table survey_details has no column named description (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO survey_details(category,locationx,locationy,date_time,description,imei) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at com.example.cmas.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:251)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-21 16:54:51.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(953):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried without the field "desc", it is working without that.What should I do?

Comment: try to increase the version of your database

Comment: try to uninstall and install app again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **desc**, because it's a reserved keyword (it's meant to be used with the ORDER BY clause):

```
public static final String COL_DESCRIPTION= "desc";
```

and

```
paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE survey_details(date_time TEXT,imei TEXT,category TEXT,locationx REAL,locationy REAL,desc TEXT);");
```

and

```
localContentValues.put("desc", "c");
```

use:

```
public static final String COL_DESCRIPTION= "description";
```

and

```
paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE survey_details(date_time TEXT,imei TEXT,category TEXT,locationx REAL,locationy REAL,description TEXT);");
```

and

```
localContentValues.put("description", "c");
```

Comment: Tried, Same error still there.04-21 17:08:36.376: E/SQLiteLog(1096): (1) table survey_details has no column named description
04-21 17:08:36.406: E/SQLiteDatabase(1096): Error inserting category=b locationx=99.999 locationy=11.77 date_time=pqr description=c imei=a
04-21 17:08:36.406: E/SQLiteDatabase(1096): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table survey_details has no column named description (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO survey_details(category,locationx,locationy,date_time,description,imei) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: see my edited answer... you have to replace "desc" EVERYWHERE it appears. (I thought you were using the COL_DESCRIPTION variable, instead of hardcoding the filed name)

Comment: BOb same problem still there dude

Comment: You have to change all three lines.

Answer (score 0):

'desc' is a SQLite 'reserved word'. Best course of action is to rename your column to something else. More here:

https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Another tip, best practice is to always use your static strings when talking to your database. You've already defined them so why not reuse them.

```
localContentValues.put(COL_DESCRIPTION, "iliketurtles");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
`localContentValues.put("desc", "c");`
```

to

```
localContentValues.put(COL_DESCRIPTION, "c");
```